# How to view pdf file without download available in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

```
import file from '../../guidesPdf';

 const handleFile = (fileName) => {
        window.open(`${file}/${fileName}`);
    }

    {guidePdf.map(edu =>
    <button className="btn btnService" 
    onClick={() =>handleFile(edu.fileName)}>Read More</button>}
```

What I try to do is view pdf files I stored in the directory. I want to view the file and make sure nobody downloads these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

In order for the browser to render the PDF, the PDF data has to be transferred to the browser.

That **is** downloading.

If the data can be transferred to the browser, then the user of the browser (who is in control of the browser because it is *their* browser) can do what they like with the data (including saving it to a PDF file on their local disk).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party library such as [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

I found [this tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-pdfs-but-prevent-them-from-downloading-in-react-2e77292ca9a5) helpful  when adding such functionality to my application